# API Response image URL not displaying image in flutter

Tags: image, flutter

I am trying to show an image which comes from an API response but it's not displaying anything.

I am able to display the image URL, but not the actual image.

Here is my code:

API call:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    showProgressBar = true;

    customFun.readToken().then((val) {
      setState(() {
        access_token = val;
      });
      (() async {
       await restApis.getProfile(access_token).then((val) => setState((){
         print(val);
          name = val["data"]["name"];
          _nameController.text = val["data"]["name"];
          _emailController.text = val["data"]["email"];
          _mobileController.text = (val["data"]["contact_number"]).toString();

          profile_image = val["data"]["avatarUrl"];

          print("-----------------------");
          print(profile_image);
          print("-----------------------");
          showProgressBar = false;
        }));
      })();
    });

  }
```

Here is displaying image code:

```
(profile_image != '') ?
                           Container(
                             width: 150.0,
                             height: 150.0,
                             decoration: BoxDecoration(
                               shape: BoxShape.circle,
                               border: Border.all(
                                 width: 1.0,
                                 color: Colors.black
                               ),
                               image: DecorationImage(
                                 image: NetworkImage("$profile_image"),
                                 fit: BoxFit.fill
                               ),

                             ),
                           ): Container(),
```

Here is displaying image URL in Text which is working fine:

```
Container(
                             child: Text("$profile_image")
                           ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `setState`,

```
customFun.readToken().then((val) {
  setState(() {
    access_token = val;
  });
  (() async {
    await restApis.getProfile(access_token).then((val) => setState((){
      print(val);
      name = val["data"]["name"];
      _nameController.text = val["data"]["name"];
      _emailController.text = val["data"]["email"];
      _mobileController.text = (val["data"]["contact_number"]).toString();

      profile_image = val["data"]["avatarUrl"];

      print("-----------------------");
      print(profile_image);
      print("-----------------------");
      showProgressBar = false;
    }));
    setState((){}); //TODO: ADD THIS
  })();
});
```

Comment: I used the same code but still nothing work. Live url is working but server URL is not working: Live image URL "https://www.projectplace.com/Global/images_NEW/icons/large/online-member-management-icon.png" And this is server URL which is not working "https://helpmeasap.24livehost.com/panel/images/user-image.png"

Comment: @RahulMishra Its because your Server URL doesn't have valid SSL Certificate. try using `http://...` instead of `https://....`